# Dynamic number of columns in spark dataframes

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

How to create dynamic number of columns in dataframe in spark using scala?
For ex: if condition is true i want 4 columns in dataframe and if condition is false i want to create 3 columns using .withColumn()
I am avoiding normal if else here and the use of var df.
Is there any method which can be applied on field itself to check and create columns dynamically.

Comment: What is the condition. Add an example. Based on that condition you can create a df with a specified schema or other

Comment: If freq is monthly or quaterly i will add one column as "frequency" with value M/Q else no "frequency" column

Comment: is that condition provided at compile time or at runtime time?

Comment: That condition will be computed in code itself...for ex it will read file and based on that ot will calculate whether it is monthly,quaterly or any other